# Fatal error: "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run the login it gives this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/lankaf5/public_html/admin/admin/functions.php on line 30

I have marked the line 30 that it's referring to; can someone please check and tell what's wrong? I tried all possible ways, but can't figure it out.

```
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);


 function login($email, $password, $conn) {;
    $sql ="SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) { // line 30 that the error is referring to
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // hash the password with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 

        if (checkbrute($user_id, $conn) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            return false;
        } else {
```

Comment: At the top of your function please put `var_dump($conn);die;` and tell us what it says.

Comment: First you have a open if statement at the top and then a function with a useless semicolon at the beginning

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: @CoolGuy: the proposed edit (to remove user-specific paths from the title) is acceptable, since it will have no applicability to any other user with the same problem. Often when editing, I copy the highly localised error into the body of the question, and make the title more generic. Don't forget that questions here are meant to be useful for future readers, not just the OP (even if this one is possibly a duplicate).

Comment: And @Benka too, see above.

Comment: when i put the var_dump($conn);die; at the beginning it gives a NULL

Comment: the same code i used on another website as well. and it worked perfectly but on this web site its not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this fix first:

```
function login($email, $password, $conn) {; // <-- remove the semi-colon
```

Now add this adjustment:

```
function login($email, $password, mysqli $conn) {
```

This will force the connection to be a `mysqli` class, and on the occasions it is not set, it will throw a fatal error closer to the source of the problem.

You will still need to find out *why* this is failing. I suspect your database credentials are incorrect, or perhaps you have not set a connection when you call this function at all?

Comment: by removing it  it made no difference

Comment: when i didt the change as you have it gave me a error saying  Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to login() must be an instance of mysqli, null given, called in /home/lankaf5/public_html/admin/admin/process_login.php on line 11 and defined in /home/lankaf5/public_html/admin/admin/functions.php on line 27

Comment: Exactly! That indicates where your error is - it is in process_login.php on line 11. Fix the problem there, or edit that code into your original question and ping me when it is done. This process is the essence of debugging - it is the repeated tracing of a problem until the source of the issue is discovered.

Comment: databse connection has no error as well because by add functions and update functions are working perfectly...

Comment: many thanks.... solved... have given the connection name wrong there..... typo.. thanks alot

Comment: Excellent @shav. If this answer was helpful, we encourage posters to click the 'tick' mark to the left, to mark it as resolved.